# Use of undeclared identifier after if/else if branch

Tags: c++, if-statement, identifier

```
P* pFactory(const std::string& pName){
    if (p == "s")
        SP newP;
    else if(pName == "f")
        FP newP;
    else if(pName == "l")
        LP newP;
    else if(pName == "i")
        IP newP;
    else if(pName == "g")
        GP newP;
    else if (pName == "n")
        NP newP;

    P* p_ptr = &newP;

return nullptr;
}
```

Basically, the function is supposed to return a pointer to a new P object that gets made depending on the pName input. I'm getting a Use of undeclared identifier 'newP' error on the pointer line.

I thought it could be because there's no final else so the object might never be created, but replacing the last else if with else didn't help. What's causing this error?

Edit:

```
P* newP = nullptr;
    
    if (pName== "s")
        newP = new SP;
    else if(pName == "f")
        newP = new FP;
    else if(pName == "l")
        newP = new LP;
    else if(pName == "i")
        newP = new IP;
    else if(pName == "g")
        newP = new GP;
    else if (pName == "n")
        newP = new NP;
    
    
    return newP;
```

would this work?

Comment: If else statements have their own scope, so you can't access variables specified in them. Declare the variable above the if else block and assign the value inside the if else. Also, taking the reference of a stack created object and returning it is the worst thing you could possibly do because that variable will go out of scope after the function exits.

Comment: Oh I missed the part in my instructions that said to create it on the heap

Comment: How would I declare it first? I'm not assigning anything to newP, just trying to decide which kind of P to create. P is an abstract class, and SP, FP, LP etc inherit from P. Is it possible to create an object and in the if else statement specify which kind I want it to be?

Comment: By the way, you're *unconditionally* return `nullptr`, *always*. Not to mention you get pointer to local variables, pointers which will immediately become (or already are) invalid (see previous comment about scope and life-time).

Comment: Multiple `return` statements could remove the need to declare any variables.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude Honestly you're not wrong, I've been out from school for the first month because of Covid issues with me and my family, so I'm trying to catch up on homework while referring to lectures. I edited the question with what I have now, is it any better?

Comment: @KevinYoon Editing an answer into a question makes the question worse, not better. You should be able to test your solution yourself to see if it solves the problem. If it does, post it as an answer (preferably with an explanation of why it is an answer).

Comment: @jamit oh okay sorry im new to stack overflow and in a rush to finish this. I didn't realize I should answer my own question, but I definitely will once I'm finished. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

If-else, statements have their own scope, so you can't access variables specified in them. Declare the variable above the if-else block and assign the value inside the if-else.

Also, taking the reference of a stack created object and returning it is the worst thing you could do because that variable will go out of scope after the function exits creating a dangling pointer.

You can make use of smart pointers to have the memory management done for you.

Here's an example of what this could look like:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct P {};
struct A : public P {};
struct B : public P {};
struct C : public P {};

std::unique_ptr<P> pFactory(const std::string& pName) 
{
    std::unique_ptr<P> p_ptr;

    if (pName == "s")
        p_ptr = std::make_unique<A>();
    else if (pName == "f")
        p_ptr = std::make_unique<B>();
    else if (pName == "l")
        p_ptr = std::make_unique<C>();
    
    return p_ptr;
}

int main() 
{
    const auto fFactory = pFactory("f");
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/7drW8a)

Comment: There is little value in editing the question, after an answer is posted, to provide an alternative answer in the question.